# Are there any drinking-water fountains in Prague PRG airport?

Tags: food-and-drink, tap-water, prague, prg

I've recently started using the take-an-empty-water-bottle-through-security technique hoping to fill it in once I pass the security checks. I'm not a big fan of overpriced bottled water.

Are there any drinking-water fountains in Prague Vaclav Havel (PRG) airport, be it airside and/or at departures/arrivals level?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes there are drinking-water fountains at PRG airport. Below is an incomplete list (feel free to edit with more information). At the time of writing (07/2015) the fountains look something like this:

[image: PRG water fountains]
<sup>*Water fountain at PRG airport*, JoErNanO, Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0</sup>

#### Terminal 1 (all flights to non-Schengen countries)

- 1 fountain outside the toilets, exact opposite of gate A2 (20161210)

[image: PRG Terminal 1, opposite Gate A2, after Passport Control]

#### Terminal 2 (all flights to Schengen countries)

- 2 fountains outside the toilets in front of gate C3

Comment: Unrelated to your answer, but what is "Creative Commons" supposed to mean? 1. Any content you post on SE is already automatically CC-BY-SA. 2. There is no single "Creative Commons" license, there are several variants, which differ significantly.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Water Fountain across from Gate C3]

Here is a picture of the fountain across from **Gate C3**.

(I don’t have enough reputation to edit the above answer)

Answer (score 2):

There is one opposite gate C12 too